# Why do we have problems with the location tags in web.config under IIS7.5?

Tags: iis-7, web-config, iis-7.5

In IIS 7.0, having `location` tags in web.config works fine.

**Example:**

```
<configuration>
....
  <location path="export">
    <system.webServer>
      <security>
        <authentication>
          <anonymousAuthentication enabled="false"/>
          <windowsAuthentication enabled="false"/>
        </authentication>
      </security>
    </system.webServer>
  </location>
```

We recently installed Windows 7 on our machines and in IIS 7.5 all of these `location` tags do not work anymore.

Comment: You'll probably get a quicker answer for this on serverfault.com seeing as it's about IIS configuration.

Answer (score -1):

Can you try `<system.web>` instead of  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b6x6shw7.aspx

Comment: The `security/authentication` config settings only apply to `system.webServer`. Putting this in `system.web` will have no effect and in fact cause an error.